# Android Studio Correct way of creating Database and Schema

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite

I just started learning Android's SQLite and **totally** new the APIs and methods used with the Database Helper. There are some code snippets and tutorials I'm following. I would like to know which is the correct way of creating the tables and database of the two code samples.

**CODE SAMPLE 1**

```
public static final String KEY_ID = "ID" ;
public static final String KEY_FNAME = "FirstName";
public static final String KEY_LNAME = "LastName";
public static final String KEY_MNAME = "MiddleName";

public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "myDb";
public static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "myTable";
public static final int DATABASE_VERSION =1;

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db){
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE +"("+ KEY_ID + "TEXT PRIMARY KEY, " + KEY_FNAME + "TEXT,"+ KEY_LNAME + "TEXT,"+KEY_MNAME+ "TEXT )");
}
```

I don't know why `"TEXT,"` has to be included and why KEY_ID was declared `TEXT` instead of `INTEGER`
(**These are codes I found online**) Tested it but didn't work.

**CODE SAMPLE 2**

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {


    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "student.db";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "student_table";
    public static final String COL_1 = "ID";
    public static final String COL_2 = "NAME";
    public static final String COL_3 = "SURNAME";
    public static final String COL_4 = "MARKS";

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, NAME TEXT, SURNAME TEXT, MARKS INTEGER) ");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);
    }
}
```

**CODE SAMPLE 2** appears to be easier for me to understand.
So far, what I understand is that

`SQLiteOpenHelper` is used to create database and tables and to call methods needed to manipulate `CRUD`

`execSQL()` is used to execute `SQL` statements

Between the two sample codes i found online, which is the correct way or structuring of code?

Are both correct? If not, how can I improve it?

Thanks.

Comment: Just a note on your `onUpgrade` code:  You probably don't want to erase all the user's data and recreate the database.  You want to make targeted changes to the schema based on which version of the database the user already has.  And the versioning of the schema is something you handle yourself in application code.

Answer (score -1):

[Here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html) Is Android "official" style of creating schemas.
That being said go with the one you understand the most, specially if you are learning.

Comment: This is a link-only answer that now points to Room so it's useless